# Bash script - Get file name with Curl after POST

Tags: bash, curl

I am coding a bash script to download a file from remote website.However, remote website requires first to submit a POST form and then it returns a file.I managed to find the solution for that and it works great.Here is it:

```
curl -F 'data=filename.rar' --user-agent 'Mozilla/4.0 POST' http://somewebsite.com/index.html -v > filename
```

Now, the problem is that I have to redirect STDOUT when the server returns that file, or I'll get gibberish code on my screen.What I want is, instead of hardcoded 'filename', to get real name of the file and to redirect STDOUT there.
Running curl with -sI options to get headers and then parse for filename is not the the solution here, because curl doesn't accept mix of -I and -F options.It has to be one of them,but only with -F I can see headers and the server also sends file along with them.Is there a way to get only headers(remember, I have also to send post data in order to get a file) so I can parse them and extract a filename ? I would then make new curl request but now with that file name as STDOUT value.Or maybe there is way to make curl to automatically download to filename from headers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment to my previous answer you may want to try wget instead.

```
FILENAME=`wget --post-file=filename.rar -P dir_to_save_files http://somewebsite.com/index.html | grep "filename" | cut -d"=" -f2 | awk '{print$1}'`; wget --post-file=filename.rar -O $FILENAME -P dir_to_save_files http://somewebsite.com/index.html
```

You may need to play around with this some as I do not have a way of testing.  You can also use the --post-data=data if it is not actually a file being posted.

- Edit based on comments.  This is probably not the most elegant way but it should be relatively effective.  You may need to play around with the cut statement and grep statement to get it to target the actual filename.

Comment: Just tried with Wget.Unfortunately, wget downloads the file, but it keeps the name 'index.php'.Don't know how to make it to keep original file name.

Comment: Here's a little more info.With --server-response I can get the headers and here is a line from output "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filenameblablabla.ZIP" Now If I could just get Wget to use that name instead of index.php...

Comment: My edit may help, if not provide an idea for the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the -o option with curl.  For example:

```
curl -F 'data=filename.rar' --user-agent 'Mozilla/4.0 POST' -o outputFileName http://somewebsite.com/index.html -v
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but -o is practically what output redirector does.I hoped somehow that there is an option that will find file name from the headers and output data there, but seems there's not.

Answer (score 0):

Finally...the solution is to use --content-disposition option with Wget to keep original file name.

Comment: ... which is basically the same option called -J, --remote-header-name with curl